# Why is Regex.Replace ignoring the negation grouping in this code?

Tags: c#, regex

This should be an easy one.

I'm trying to replace any character that is not a letter, number or whitespace with empty string.

```
 title = Regex.Replace(title, "[^A-Z0-9\\ ]", "");
```

The regex behaves correctly in Regex Hero http://regexhero.net/tester/ which I believe uses the C# engine.

However with my code, for the string "Case Study 5" I get title as "  5", seemingly ignoring the negation.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx my syntax is correct.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
 title = Regex.Replace(title, "[^a-zA-Z0-9\\ ]", "");
```

Note: be careful this also remove é, è, etc which are letter but not located between a-z characters.
If you want to keep them, you may want something like this

```
 title = Regex.Replace(title, @"[^\w\ ]", "");
```

So "Casé Stu-dy 5" becomes "Casé Study 5"

Answer (score 2):

No need to use regex:

```
title = new string(title.Where(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == ' ').ToArray());
```